# Pathway to directory lost in R studio

Tags: rstudio

I am relatively new to R studio, I am attempting to import a .RNK file to run on GSEA. However, the pathway to my working directory is lost and I keep receiving a file, "rt" warning message.

When comparing my working directory with my usual windows explorer file, the files themselves are absent from the working directory.

I have attempted to change the Default text encoding to UTF-8 but this has had no effect. I would be grateful for any suggestions to help with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very common problem!

You have four options to select the correct file and path! Hope at least one can work well.

1. Manually without code, you can go to the top and choose Session->Set Working Directory -> Choose Directory... and then select the file.
2. You can just use the function `file. choose()` and look for the file on your computer and select it.
3. You can look for the file path on your computer and write it in R. Look in the local search engine for your computer and search for the file. For example: `setwd("~/Desktop/University/Homework")`
4. You can use getwd() in the console to know where the script is working and saving the files and then look for the files there!

PD: the best way to work in R and R-Studio/Posit for me is by creating a project. Doing so, you will have everything related to the script in one folder (new and old files!). It is similar to `setwd()`but better!